# AWS - Add existing load balancer to target group

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am trying to add a load balancer to a target group.

In EC2 > Target Groups, I can see my target group that I want to add an existing load balancer to.

[image]

So I select "Associate with an existing load balancer" which brings me to this page.

[image]

I then select the load balancer... but then what? There's no button that says "Add load balancer to target group". The "Create Load balancer" blue button is there to create a new load balancer (not what I want). It doesn't look like anything in the "Actions" dropdown is appropriate. How can I attach the selected load balancer to the target group?

Comment: Do you have a listener on the load balancer?

Comment: @Paolo yes, I have 2 listeners on the load balancer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I agree that the UI in this case is not very self-explanatory. You should read the documentation (e.g. [Target groups for your Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-target-groups.html)) first to get a general understanding of the relationship between a load balancer (LB) and a target group (TG). TL;DR, the TG is not associated to an LB directly. Instead, they are associated via a listener.

> A listener is a process that checks for connection requests, using the protocol and port that you configure. The rules that you define for a listener determine how the load balancer routes requests to its registered targets.

Source: [Listeners for your Application Load Balancers](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticloadbalancing/latest/application/load-balancer-listeners.html)

Therefore, the correct steps to take after clicking the "Associate with an existing load balancer" are:

1. Select a load balancer
2. Go to "Listeners" tab
3. Either edit an existing listener or add a new listener
4. Set rules and conditions, and attach TG

Comment: Yes, I have the listeners selected in the Listeners tab. However, I do not see any button or anything to allow me to complete step 4. Thanks